# Allow INI file access to only specified clients

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to secure some files on my Apache Server.
The file extension is **.ini**

Now I tried this using .htaccess

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost.*$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule \.(ini)$ - [F]
```

This forbids everyone to access these files, but I want to allow some users/clients/or any one with valid credentials to access these.

My root directory has something like this :

```
/var/www/html/project/base_ini/my.ini
```

Now I want that if I open :

```
https://localhost/project/base_ini/my.ini
```

Apache/PHP or .htacess should forbid it.

**But**

If any specified client tries to access these, it should allow it.
By client I mean my Android/iPhone application should be allowed, but not the browser.

What are my options ?

Comment: Create PHP script that checks permissions and then prints out `my.ini` file content

Comment: @Justinas my files are already created, they are just static files. if i use PHP then i might need to store paths and names in DB. i want something which can allow better access control over the files or maybe something like i can check the user agent and if matches my requirement then only allow